# WASM link error: function signature mismatch

Tags: c++, emscripten, mismatch

I've been using WASM via emscripten for a few weeks now and had been making good progress, until this error:

```
exception thrown: RuntimeError: function signature mismatch,RuntimeError: function signature mismatch
```

This started happening in code that previously worked and seems to be something to do with WASMs lack of support for 64bit integers in javascript and the offsets used in file management. I've made an isolated case:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    char test[30];
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    FILE *f = fopen("minimal_call_dispatch.cpp","ra");
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl; 
    fseek(f, 100, SEEK_SET);
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    fclose(f);
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

building with:

```
call emcc -o ./test.js test_file.cpp -s WASM=1 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -std=c++1z
```

Which outputs '6\n8\n' before failing on 'fseek' due to the mentioned error.

Somewhere along the line, I suspect that wasm is trying to use headers that communicate with javascript that have 64bit integers instead of 32bit ones but I can't see how that could have happened. 
I'm going to try re-installing emscripten but even if that works, I'd like to get a better idea of what's causing this.

As a work around, does anybody know how to get emcc to ignore worries over 64bit integers and silently convert them to 32bit? I'm not looking to address more than 3gigs of ram, after all.

Comment: Why are you mentioning 64-bit int when the code doesn't seem to do anything with 64-bit?

Comment: And where is your `minimal_call_dispatch.cpp` that you are opening? Are you opening the file you shipped, or are you creating the file?

Comment: The filename isn't relevant here: it could be anything. That file was simply something in my working directory.

The 64bit issue is a suggestion of what I *think* might be the problem from having seen others have issues with 64bit int and wasm function linking. My suspicion is that, for some,  reason the code thinks that 'size_t' is a 'long long' a 64bit int (as it is when building c++ for 64bit) rather than a 32bit value.


The problem is that WASM barfs when it gets to fseek and I'd like to know if anybody else has this problem and, if so, how they fixed it.

Comment: No, the file matters. Do you expect the file is created, or  are you opening an existing file on this code. I already got the answer but I'm making sure what you really expect from the code before posting the answer.

Comment: Some implementations of fseek specify the offset as a 'long int', which would likely cause problems for WASM. 
  One thing I did around the time it stopped working was to try and create a make file for the project, rather than doing it all from one line. 
  That attempt failed: some obscure error in a python file about finding interpreters, so I gave up on that can of worms for now but perhaps it's corrupted some emscripten file somewhere, causing it to get C headers from another place, one with 'long int' in its fseek implementation? These are just guesses, by the way.

Comment: really, it doesn't. Make another file, call it bob.txt, it really isn't the salient point here :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206065/discussion-between-luther-and-bumsik-kim).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the error simply because your code is wrong.

1. You really don't need to worry about 32bit/64bit stuff. The current WebAssembly spec do not have 64-bit machine and it only have 32-bit addresses (but it supports 64-bit integer `i64` internally and calculates 64-bit integers well. It just doesn't have 64-bit addresses.) 
   This means that the compiler is already knows the target machine is 32-bit and `size_t` will be 32-bit as will.
2. In the comments, I asked if you want to open the file or want to create the file. **This is important because using `"ra"` with `fopen()` will cause segmentation fault when the file doesn't exist because of `r` flag!**

Okay, lets try this in the native environment.

```
g++ test_file.cpp -o test.out
```

running `./test.out` will prints the following if `test_file.cpp` doesn't exist:

```
6
8
[2]    14464 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./test.out
```

So your code is wrong, but why Emscripten throws the error differently? When you use `emcc` without debugging flags like `-g`, it will have the minimized environment that doesn't catch errors like segfault because such smart runtime will increase the binary size which is critical in the web environment. As a result the runtime keeps running ignoring segfualt and it will end up with a random error. So `function signature mismatch` doesn't mean anything.

You can build it using debugging-related options:

```
emcc -o ./test.html  test_file.cpp -s WASM=1 -std=c++1z \
    -g4 -s ASSERTIONS=2 -s SAFE_HEAP=1 -s STACK_OVERFLOW_CHECK=1 \
    --source-map-base http://your_server_ip:port/
```

Then opening `test.html` you will see the correct error now:

```
exception thrown: RuntimeError: abort(segmentation fault) at Error
```

Now you won't get the misleading errors like signature mismatch :)

By the way, replace `fopen("minimal_call_dispatch.cpp","ra");` with `fopen("minimal_call_dispatch.cpp","a");` will fix the error.

With the correct `--source-map-base` server IP settings, you will have a better debugging experience. For example, you will get the source `test_file.cpp` in the browser so that you can set breakpoints to the .cpp file.

Have fun with debugging :)

Comment: Thanks for the response but that file _does_ exist on my machine - I'm getting past 'fopen' and it's then failing on 'fseek' due to the 'function signature mismatch' call.
Regarding --source-map-base - yes, that's something I really want to get working but it seems it doesn't work with the emscripten toolchain at the moment. Apparently it does with the alternative 'Cheerp' but I haven't tried it yet (one problem at a time :)

Comment: Hmm...--source-map-base works in my machine though. Are you running it in a web browser, or nodejs? If it is in the web environment, you will get a clean filesystem in the browser with zero files because the browser cannot get the file from your machine.

Comment: See "Packaging files" section from [the docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/files/index.html) You will likely end up with using Emscripten-specific file APIs because the limitations of the web environment.

Comment: I'm running through the browser and I've been using the file packager but thinking on it, I don't think this particular test file was included in that, although the error was the same as in my main project (which is larger and more cumbersome to work with, hence this minimal test). I'll give it another go later today (I'm not on that machine right now). 
I'll have a look at --source-map-base too, although the problem I encountered was to do with generating the source maps to start with - emcc didn't seem to want to generate them.

Comment: All, sorry, I take it all back: I was thrown by the error message. I build the data file correctly for the test and it worked fine. I even got source mapping working: that's failing on my main project more likely because it's rather huge. Thanks for the help.

Comment: although, in my main project, the problem remains - and it gets past the 'if (file != NULL)'  check too. Ah well, back to square one :/